# Tangent bundle of $S^n$ diffeomorphic to subspace of $S^n \times \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: differential-geometry

A set of lecture notes on differential geometry I was reading noted that the tangent bundle of a standard n-sphere $TS^n$ is diffeomorphic to the space $\{(x, y) \in S^n \times \mathbb{R}^{n+1}| <x, y> = 0 \}$. Why is this true?

Comment: Maybe think of $S^2$ helps you. Given $x\in S^2$, what is $T_x S^2$? How can you characterised it?

Comment: Actually thinking of $S^1$ is even easier, then you can draw what happens.

Answer (score 4):

If $S\subset M$ is a submanifold of an ambiant manifold, you can see the tangent space of $S$ at a point $p$ as a linear subspace of the tangent space of $M$ at $p$, under the identification $i_{\star,p}:T_pS\to T_pM$, where $i:S\to M$ is the inclusion. Moreover, if the ambient one is an affine subspace, a tangent vector at a point $p$ is identified with a vector of the underlying vector space (in the case of $\mathbb{R}^n$, this is no more that $\mathbb{R}^n\to T_p\mathbb{R}^n, v\mapsto \partial_v=$ the directionnal derivative at the point $p$ in the direction of $v$). So the following computations are right under the identifications that I precised above:

Take a smooth curve $\gamma:(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\to S^n$ with $\gamma(0)=x\in S^n$ and $\gamma'(0)=y\in T_pS^n$. Since $||\gamma(t)||^2=\langle\gamma(t),\gamma(t)\rangle=1$ for all $t$, then by differentiating and evaluating at $0$ you get

$$2\cdot\langle\gamma(0),\gamma'(0)\rangle=0\iff\langle x,y\rangle = 0.$$

This leads to the identification you are given.